# How do I correctly index into an array of struct pointers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Here is the code I'm looking at:

```
void add_to_pfds(struct pollfd *pfds[], int newfd, int *fd_count, 
      int *fd_size)
{
     // If we don't have room, add more space in the pfds array
     if (*fd_count == *fd_size) {
        *fd_size *= 2; // Double it

        *pfds = realloc(*pfds, sizeof(**pfds) * (*fd_size));
     }

    (*pfds)[*fd_count].fd = newfd;
    (*pfds)[*fd_count].events = POLLIN; // Check ready-to-read

    (*fd_count)++;
}
```

If this looks familiar, it's because it's from Beej's Guide to Network Programming.

The part I'm having trouble understanding is `(*pfds)[*fd_count].fd = newfd;`. `pfds` is an array of struct pollfd pointers. In my understanding, `(*pfds)` first dereferences the array, resulting in a single struct pollfd pointer, the first element of the array. We then index into the array, to index `*fd_count`. Shouldn't this result in another pollfd pointer? How then are we using the period operator to access the `.fd` member of that struct? Shouldn't we be using the -> operator instead?

I'm missing something somewhere. Can somebody give me a correct way to think about this?

Comment: The confusion here is partially caused by the notation.  Change `void add_to_pfds(struct pollfd *pfds[], ...` to the more reasonable `void add_to_pfds(struct pollfd **pfds, ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct pollfd *pfds[]` is a pointer to a pointer to `struct pollfd`. (This is a pointer instead of an array because this is a function argument)

`(*pfds)` is a pointer to `struct pollfd`. This is equivalent to `pfds[0]`.

`(*pfds)[*fd_count]`, which is equivalent to `pfds[0][*fd_count]`, is a `struct pollfd`. It it natural to use a dot `.` operator to access members of a `struct`.